# C#: Get WindowHandles of all windows by Processname

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, forms

there is a application with 5 windows.
i have the PID of that process, and how can i get **all** WindowHandles of that Process?

thanks.

Comment: Get the MainWindowHandle ans then call [EnumChildWindows](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumchildwindows) on it.

Answer (score 1):

Get the MainWindowHandle and then call [**EnumChildWindows**](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumchildwindows) on it.

Maybe calling managed code will be better than **PInvoke**, you can find more here [**Managed Windows API**](http://mwinapi.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Start with some PInvoke stuff described in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/magazine/cc301495%28en-us%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

User something like this:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses(".");
foreach (var process in processes)
{
    var handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
}
```

Comment: ok. You could iterate over all the windows and retrieve the process ID from the HWND and match this process ID with the ID you are interested in. Check out GetWindowThreadProcessId